# how to put the products of the mobile version of my site in two columns?

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm developing a gaming site with the woocommerce platform, everything was going well until the customer asked me to separate the products into two columns, but for being a self-supporting company, at a certain width, the site organizes them into one, could you help me ?

In other forums I found suggestions for similar problems like this:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 570px)
```

but I did not succeed, I do not know if for some mistake of mine, but it went wrong

Currently the mobile version concentrates all the products in single queue,

I would like the display to follow in two queues as already happens in other devices with larger screens, and if possible, in those other devices, that the display was of 4 columns of products per line

Comment: This is the site I would like to split into two columns per line in the mobile version https://safari.avner.com.br/shop/

Comment: This question in its current form is too broad. There is no code for us to work with. Just the media query isn't telling us anything. Don't link to outside source we are not going to dig trough your websites code we only look at a relevant code snippet

Comment: @SuperDJ in the page that I added the question, in the mobile version, the products are in 1 column, I need help dividing them in two

Comment: Like I said add the relevant code in a snippet in the question do not link to it. If your site would change the question wouldn't make sense without it

Comment: you have a lot of methods to do that but we need to see your code or at least an example so we can help you

Comment: more specifically, please show us the relevant html + css bits that you have already and better create an SO snippet (see also [mcve])